# How can I make a movable <hr>?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a question. How can I create a movable `<hr>` and move it over image?
I thought about changing the parameter "margin", but I don't know how put the `<hr>` over the image.

Please help me if you can.

Comment: Please [create and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code

Comment: Same way you overlay any other html on image. Need to absolute position in parent container of image

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @kipill, Stackoverflow employs rules as to encourage maintainable questions and answers that have longevity. A good place to start is to post your own broken code and we can try help you with it. Make sure you read chazsolo's link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on: https://jsfiddle.net/tovic/Xcb8d/

CSS

```
#draggable-hr {
    cursor:move;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<hr id="draggable-hr">
```

JavaScript

```
var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

    // Will be called when user starts dragging an element
    function _drag_init(elem) {
        // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
        selected = elem;
        x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
        y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
    }

    // Will be called when user dragging an element
    function _move_elem(e) {
        x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
        y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
        if (selected !== null) {
            selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
            selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
        }
    }

    // Destroy the object when we are done
    function _destroy() {
        selected = null;
    }

    // Bind the functions...
    document.getElementById('draggable-hr').onmousedown = function () {
        _drag_init(this);
        return false;
    };

    document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
    document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that?

You want to draw a line in a image right? Why don't use canvas for that? Here's an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/vo769cfx

```
  Original image:
<br>
<br>
<img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream">
<br> Canvas:
<br>
<br>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="320" height="277"></canvas>

  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("scream");

  ctx.drawImage(img, 50, 0);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 138);
  ctx.lineTo(320, 138);
  ctx.stroke();
```

You just need to redraw the line each time you click or drag in the canvas.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about canvas, but I didn't see this example earlier. I do it because I can have an ability for move this line.